# Number 5 seeds hosting NFL conference championship game

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl, postseason

Under the current format that 6 teams from each conference make it to the playoffs, how many times has a #5 seed hosted the conference championship game?

In order for the #5 seed to host the game, both the #5 and the #6 seed have to upset their higher seeded opponents in the wild card and the divisional round. So an equivalent question would be how many times the #5 and #6 seeds of a conference have met in the AFC or NFC championship game?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Under the current format that 6 teams from each conference make it to the playoffs

Note: This format has been used since 1990<sub>[(1)](http://profootballtalk.nbcsports.com/2015/03/02/nfls-12-team-playoff-format-enacted-25-years-ago-this-week/)</sub>.

> how many times has a #5 seed hosted the conference championship game?

0 times.

Only twice since 1990 has a #1 or #2 seed not been involved in a conference championship:

- [2006 AFC Championship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006%E2%80%9307_NFL_playoffs#Bracket) (#3 Colts vs #4 Patriots)
- [2008 NFC Championship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008%E2%80%9309_NFL_playoffs#Bracket) (#4 Cardinals vs #6 Eagles)

---

Moreover, a #5 seed vs. a #6 seed would require one of those seeds to reach the Super Bowl<sub>[(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010%E2%80%9311_NFL_playoffs#Bracket)</sub>.

Only one #5 seed has reached the Super Bowl:

- [2007 Giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007%E2%80%9308_NFL_playoffs#Bracket) - faced the #2 seed Green Bay Packers in the NFC championship.

Only two #6 seeds have reached the Super Bowl:

- [2005 Steelers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005%E2%80%9306_NFL_playoffs#Bracket) - faced the #2 seed Denver Broncos in the AFC Championship
- [2010 Packers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010%E2%80%9311_NFL_playoffs#Bracket) - faced the #2 seed Chicago Bears in the NFC Championship

Aside: Coincidentally, the three times a #5 or #6 seed reached the Super Bowl, they went on to win.